# append onclick event to anchor element that returns id

Tags: javascript

below I'm trying to add new anchor elements to the DOM.
I also like to add an onclick event to each new created element that returns its id, but can't get it done.
All help is welcome!

```
var text = document.getElementById("output");

for (var i = 0; i < uld.length; i++){ 

var x = document.createElement("A");
var t = document.createTextNode(uld[i][1]);
x.setAttribute('id', i);
x.onclick = function getId() {alert("kikker");};
x.appendChild(t);

text.appendChild(x);
}
```

Comment: You code works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uzrmwb05/

Comment: @j08691 it does not return the id but the string "kikker" instead. the id will be a number created by `i`

Comment: Ah, I thought your issue was that the alert wasn't firing.

Comment: Here's the code with the ID alerting http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uzrmwb05/1/

Comment: @Ethannn: Well, that's because you have `alert("kikker")`.  What's the *real* issue here?

Comment: thanks @j08691 that did the trick. I knew about the this pointer but did not know how to use it in this construction. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'this' pointer in a onclick is refering to the element.
So you could use the 'id' like this:

```
var text = document.getElementById("output");

var i;
for (i = 0; i < uld.length; i++) { 
    var x = document.createElement("A");
    var t = document.createTextNode(uld[i][1]);
    x.setAttribute("id", i);

    x.onclick = function() {
        var id = this.id;
        alert(id);
    };

    x.appendChild(t);
    text.appendChild(x);
}
```